# How to have separator inside SVG Text Element?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg like below

[Svg element with seprator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hyfma.png)

And this is what it looks like in svg element

```
<text x="-50" y="-15" dy=".6em" style="dominant-baseline: central;">
<tspan class="t-text-seperator" dx="0em">Java Enterprise Edition</tspan>
<tspan dx="0.35em" class="t-span-seperator">|</tspan>
<tspan dx="0.35em" class="skill-icon-low"></tspan>
</text>
```

I want to have a separator between Java Enterprise Edition and Icon which span entirely instead of '|' how can i achieve this.

Comment: It looks fine to me. Maybe your problem is that text falls outside the svg canvas. Please try viewBox="-50 -14 200 20" for the svg element

Comment: Could you make your code into a complete svg? That way it is easier for us to help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)